# JSTL c:if tag does not seem to have any effect

Tags: jsp, jstl

I've got the following code I am trying to switch from scriptlet:

```
    <% if (session.getAttribute("korisnik") == null) { %>
    <a href='login.jsp'>Ulogujte se</a>
    <a href='registracija.jsp'>Registrujte se</a>
    <% } %>
```

to el:

```
    <c:if test="${sessionScope.korisnik == null}">
    <a href='login.jsp'>Ulogujte se2</a>
    <a href='registracija.jsp'>Registrujte se2</a>
    </c:if>
```

The scriptlet code works (hides the login and register pages if user is logged in aka has data in session) but I heard that it's bad practice so am trying to switch it to EL, but the EL part doesn't work, and I tried countless variations (just korisnik, with session scope, comparing to 0 etc).

I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly obvious here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, in the end it wasn't the code itself that was the problem, it was something about the jstl jar I had placed. I downloaded a fresh 1.2 one and that did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to import the taglib like so:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Then this should work:

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.korisnik == null}">
  <a href='login.jsp'>Ulogujte se2</a>
  <a href='registracija.jsp'>Registrujte se2</a>
</c:if>
```

Make sure the taglib is above the `<html>` tag